# Enabled NSTableView refuses to resign first responder and eats all the events sent to first responder

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, nstableview, first-responder

I have an NSTableView and it eats all events sent to the first responder. Before adding table view, everything was perfect, and all the messages sent to the first responder were sent correctly to my `NSDocument` subclass.

As soos as I added table view, it insists on **always** having focus. The focus indicator around it never disappears unless an external sheet view controller (or something similar) gains focus. When table view has focus, my messages sent to the first responder doesn't work with keyboard shortcuts. They work when I click them from the menu bar by pointer though.

If I set "refuses first responder" it doesn't change anything. If I set "enabled" to false, then my app returns to normal behavior (though I obviously can't interact with the table view).

How can I prevent table view's "always focused" behavior. I've tried [In a view-based NSTableView, how make a control the first responder with a single click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148085/in-a-view-based-nstableview-how-make-a-control-the-first-responder-with-a-singl)'s answer but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've subclassed `NSTableView`, I've overridden `becomeFirstResponder` and returned NO without doing anything, and it worked great! I can interact with the table view freely, it just doesn't gain focus.